# printf and _n in this example?

Tags: text, customization

what is the last `$count` in this example?

```
printf( _n(
    'You have published %s post.', 'You have published %s posts.',
    $count,
    'myplugin' ),
$count );
```

i guess the first one is to fill each %s, so what is the second $count?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_n` ([see Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_n)) function accepts four arguments. The first two are texts to be translated (the first is singular, the second plural), the third argument is a number (in this case `$count`). When `$count` is 1 the first string is used, otherwise the second string is used.

So in fact the first instance of `$count` is only used to determine whether the single / plural text should be used. `_n` then translates that string, using the plug-in/theme domain - i.e. the fourth argument) and the language set in the wp-config. This then returns a translated string such as:

> Se han publicado %s artículos

The `printf` then echos this string with the `%s` replaced by the second argument, `$count` (which is the second instance of $count`) .